# Setting up Xcode to automatically manage your provisioning profiles - No option to Set the provisioning profile to None

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

Reading up on setting up Xcode to automatically manage your provisioning profiles here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1814/_index.html

I get as far as:

```
Once you have your team selected in the General pane, clear out any manual Code Signing settings so they can be managed automatically. To do that, edit the Code Signing section in the Build Settings pane of your Xcode project as follows:

1. Set the provisioning profile to None.
```

However, I only have `Automatic`, the list of existing Profiles (including *) and Other. Any suggestions which one to pick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably on Xcode 6, which is done a bit differently.  Read down further in that technical note for how it should look in Xcode 6 (hint - it should be "Automatic").

Comment: Yes, it's confusing that the instructions at the top are different from those below. One note though - it says "refresh your provisioning profiles in Xcode before you start using them there." - how do you do that?

Comment: Go into Xcode Preferences, then go to the accounts tab.  Select the Apple ID on the left pane.  Once you've done that, you should see your name in the right bottom pane.  Double-click that, and it should list the signing identities and provisioning profiles.  Under the provisioning profiles in the bottom left, there is a refresh button.  Click that and it should get the latest.